# Java proxy connection random failure

Tags: java, proxy, connection, httprequest

Im building one application that requests one http connection, thus I have two different situations, one while Im programming at home and another while Im at my work. In my work I have one proxy server and at home not. At home my request is always ok, in my job I receive random failures.

In my console, the stack trace points:

```
 HTTP error fetching URL. Status=503, URL=http://www.google.com/sorry/?continue=http://google.com/search%3Fq%3Dmake%2BSearch
```

Which means:

```
503 Service Unavailable. The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state.
```

So, the stack traces points the error to the google server, as its not available, but since I dont receive this error at home Im almost sure the error is with the proxy server. Copying the link of the error to the browser I could see that google is blocking the request since is a sort of automatic request. Anyway, Im using:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "");
```

to handle the proxy connection, even though its not working fully correct, sometimes the connection works, sometimes not returning the error up there. Is there anything I could possibly do to solve this situation such as refresh my IP?